# finding difference between 2 months in spark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

im trying to use function months_between in spark sql to find difference between 2 months in two different dates  however I don't want to consider number of days between the 2 months for example :
I have these 2 dates

28-1-2-21 and 4-4-2021 , I'm getting a difference =2.2 however I want value to be 3
another two dates  :
7-1-2021 and 18-3-2021 , I'm getting difference = 2.36 , I want value to be 2

I was trying to use round function but it's not accurate since for some dates I need to round up a number and for other dates I need to round down the same number ,same as the example above

the function im using months_between((date1),(date2))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the number of months regardless of dates.

In that case, you can combine `trunc` and `months_between`.

`trunc` will truncate to the unit specified by the format, so using the unit=month, you will get the first day of the month.

```
months_between(trunc('date1', 'month'), trunc('date2', 'month'))
```